# Ambiguous column name when using Filament SelectFilter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I am using Filament Tables and I am trying to make use of the Filters, specifically a `SelectFilter`.

The problem that I am running into is that the query that I need to use to populate the base table requires a join to another table that has duplicate column names as the parent.  I first ran into the ambiguous column name error when using the `searchable` method on my `TextColumn` definitions. With `searchable` you can pass the column name as a param to the method in order to fix this error like so:

```php
TextColumn::make('status')->label('Status')->searchable(['myTable.status']);
```

Unfortunately, I am running into the same ambiguous column error when I define my select filter on the status column:

```php
SelectFilter::make('status')
    ->label('Membership Status')
    ->options(['Thing1' => 'Thing 1', 'Thing2' => 'thing 2']);
```

I am not sure how to go about fixing this. I've looked in the docs and it isn't really clear what I can do. I tried to use the query method of SelectFilter, but when I do that the query appears to be executed as soon as the table loads and always returns no results. Any help is appreciated.